# Why no master node to stop appear in jps during stop-all.sh in spark?

Tags: apache-spark

I used Spark on Standalone Mode in ubuntu .I have one master and 2 worker node in virtualbox.Worker node Worked in webui but master failed .
when writting stop-all.sh `"no org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master to stop"` and master node not appear in jps.
how to solve it?

Comment: _"I used Spark on Standalone Mode in ubuntu .I have one master and 2 worker node in virtualbox."_ <-- how do you start the Spark Standalone cluster? If `jps -lm` shows no JVMs for the cluster, `stop-all.sh` will print out the message.

Comment: thanks , I use jps and all nodes work well .

Comment: Did that solve your issue? Could you include the output of `jps` and `stop-all.sh` in your question?